# Python DataFrame - how do I group and aggregate values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame

```
    restaurant_name                    rating
0   Blue Ribbon Fried Chicken              3
1   Tamarind TriBeCa                       3
2   Blue Ribbon Fried Chicken              5
3   Shake Shack                            5
4   RedFarm Hudson                         4
... ... ...
792 RedFarm Broadway                       3
793 TAO                                    5
794 Chipotle Mexican Grill $1.99 Delivery. 5
795 The Smile                              5
796 Jack's Wife Freda                      5
797 rows × 2 columns
```

I need to group rows and show sum and mean for each restaraunt.

I tried

```
filtered_df = filtered_df.groupby(['restaurant_name'])['rating'].agg(lambda x: x.unique().mean())
filtered_df
```

this shows me a weird output

```
restaurant_name
'wichcraft          NaN
12 Chairs           NaN
5 Napkin Burger     NaN
67 Burger           NaN
Alidoro             NaN
                   ... 
Zero Otto Nove      NaN
brgr                NaN
da Umberto          NaN
ilili Restaurant    4.0
indikitch           NaN
```

Comment: `filtered_df.groupby('restaurant_name')['rating'].agg(['mean', 'sum'])`

Comment: I highly suspect that your `df` has a `dtype` of object and the column "rating" contains mixed values of `int` and `NaN`. And what are you trying to accomplish with `x.unique().mean()` instead of just `x.mean()`?

Comment: Please include the results of `df.dtypes` and `df.isna().any()` in your post.

Comment: '''
    df.dtypes
'''
    restaurant_name    category
    rating                int64
    dtype: object

    filtered_df.isna().any()
    restaurant_name    False
    rating             False
    dtype: bool